# How to update line status in django-oscar?

Tags: django-oscar

I am completely new to django oscar and trying to build a project but now while doing the shipping part I am confused at the point where after placing an order, in dashboard I am not able to update the line status I am not sure if it picks up the status from settings or is there a specific place where I need to add it…

Please help, need to launch this website in 2 days...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to first define a status pipeline for your lines, using the `OSCAR_LINE_STATUS_PIPELINE` [setting](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.4/ref/settings.html#oscar-line-status-pipeline).

See also the [documentation](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html#defining-the-order-pipeline) that explains how this and the order status pipeline work:

A pipeline would look something like this

```
OSCAR_INITIAL_LINE_STATUS = 'Pending'
OSCAR_LINE_STATUS_PIPELINE = {
    'Pending': ('Being processed', 'Cancelled',),
    'Being processed': ('Processed', 'Cancelled',),
    'Cancelled': (),
}
```